# @Temporal.DATE not showing full year

Tags: java

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "CNTRT_ST_DATE")
private Date dtcntrtStDate;
```

I retrieving this value from DB  and show into a `<sj:datePicker>` field.
I want to show *MM/dd/yyyy* format but it's showing as *MM/dd/yy*.

I want to show the full year.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your `Date` and just want to print it: [Formatting a Date Using a Custom Format](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.text/formatdate.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `displayFormat` attribute of `datePicker`, like this:

```
<sj:datepicker displayFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" value="dtcntrtStDate" id="..." name="...." label="..."/>
```

if i took this displayFormat its showing date "July/17/20122012" when i click on the date picker image. so its invalid to save..